# Removing table on map using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, table, select, arcgis-10.7

I am using ArcMap 10.7 and very often I export data from attribute tables to external Excel files.

Very recently I saw several table layers appearing on my map (figure below) and I guess this was caused by some accidental uses of Ctrl+C and/or Ctrl+V. However, I do not know how to remove them! It does not help to close all the layers, and they remain there even when I close and reopen this .mxd file. It seems weird to have tables on a map!

You can see the sketch of tables in the center, at the west coasts of Africa:

[image]

As I zoom in, you can see that there are actually multiple overlapping table layers!

[image]

Comment: Where did the table appear (data view  or layout) ? Anyway you should be able to select it (with the black arrow) then delete it by pressing suppr key

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible to tell from you screenshots what exactly is there, but pasting a table from Excel for example, is certainly possible.

- Activate the *Select* tool on the *Tools* toolbar: [image: Selection tool]
- Click on the table: You will see light blue selection handles on the corners
- Press Delete (Or: Right click → Delete; Or: Delete on the *Standard* toolbar: [image: Delete tool])

Comment: Thanks so much! Could not imagine the problem can be so easily solved. I have tried the Select Features toolbar many times and did not ever think about Select!

Comment: @HanchenWANG Ah, yes. A map can contain both features (from a featureclass) and graphics, which for some reason are selected in a different way.